# Salesforce User not able to edit a Asset record that he created

Tags: profile, sharing, standard-objects, owd, edit

I have a profile whose is having Create/read/edit permissions on object level and the OWD of the object is Private. I am able to create a new record but when I try to edit the same record that I just created, I am getting the error '*Oops...you don't have the necessary privileges to edit this record. See your administrator for help.*'. The object I am using is the standard Asset object. What am I missing here for my user to be able to Edit the records he created?

Comment: Did the ownership change on the record after you saved?

Answer (score 0):

Some things to check

- CRUD permission on Asset for the running user's profile + permission sets. User might have Create permission but not Edit
- Does user have edit permission on the Asset's parent Contact and Account?

Comment: In my sandbox the sharing settings for Account,contract,Asset are combined and its private. Its not controlled by parent